# Black clouds in Texture Paint

Tags: texturing

I am trying to use the Texture Paint feature in Blender, but for some reason, the Clouds texture has black where there should not be color painted.  How do I fix this?

[image: Weird black clouds]

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 problems. I believe you are following Blender Guru's doughnut tutorial. That was the first one I followed as well.

1. Make sure to use a "Texture Mask"
2. In the drop-down titled "Brush", choose "Brush Mask - Texture"[image]

After these adjustments your brush should match Blender Guru's brush.

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of most of my screen:
[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find where that is, can you maybe show me your whole screen?

Comment: Ok, I found it but I can't add the texture mask

Comment: Also in your screenshot I see you have used a very high strength. For better quality in sculpting and texture painting, usually using a smaller strength is much better.